# Stop scrolling RecyclerView after a specific position

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I want a horizontal `RecyclerView` which stops scrolling after a specific position. Suppose there are `100[1,2,3,...]` items in `RecyclerView`, but when user scroll it, it should stop scrolling when it reached to 10th item/position. Also, a button should display after it. On clicking this button full list activity would display.

Comment: are you asking about pagination in recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

What i understand is you want to implement view more functionality. Try following code. 
If more then 10 items is there then you have to pass size of 11 to your adapter.Last 11th cell will be view more (in your case "A button").
You need to implement 2 different types of view .One with regular layout and 2nd will include your button for view more. And two viewholders in your adapter class.

```
        List<Items> item_list;
        final int TYPE_NORMAL = 0, TYPE_MORE = 1;
        boolean isMoreCellVisible = false;
        int count;

        public CustomRecycleAdapter(List<Items> item_list) {
            this.item_list = item_list;

            if (item_list.size() > 10) {
                count = 11;
                isMoreCellVisible = true;

            } else {

                count = item_list.size();
            }
        }
```

you can perform your logic which cell you want to display by following code.

```
        @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (position == 10) {
            if (isMoreCellVisible) {
                return TYPE_MORE;

            } else {

                return TYPE_NORMAL;
            }

        } else {

            return TYPE_NORMAL;
        }

    }
```

In onCreateViewHolder method check which type of cell you have to inflate,

```
switch (viewType) {

                case TYPE_NORMAL: {
                    // Return a new holder instance
                    vh = new ViewHolder0(contactView);
                }
                break;

                case TYPE_MORE: {
                    // Return a new holder instance
                    vh = new ViewHolder2(contactView);

                }
                break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

For onBindViewHolder ,

```
switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {

                case TYPE_NORMAL: {

                    ViewHolder0 vh0 = (ViewHolder0) holder;

                    vh0.txt_name.setText(item_list.get(position).getName());

                }
                break;
                case TYPE_MORE: {

                  //View more layout    
                    ViewHolder2 vh2 = (ViewHolder2) holder;

                }
                break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

In getItemCount return count simply,

```
@Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return count;
        }
```

You can set Button click event in viewholder class that include your button.You can perform anything on button click like notify adapter with all 100 records or open a new activity to show all your recoeds.

Comment: This answer is totally irrelevant. OP wants to disable scrolling after a specific position